# Determine whether to use fixed effect, random effect or mixed effect model?

Tags: mixed-model, fixed-effects-model

I have purchase panel data of consumers over a period of time (1.5 year).
Within this period of time there is an intervention of +/ - 0.2 years implemented.
this purchase data consist out of the purchase of products.
These products can belong to a productgroup (in total 10 productsgroups)

I am interested in the effect of the intervention on the sales of the product for each category (and compare them?). Furthermore, i do have some interaction variables with the intervention variable, so i can analyze what the effect of these variables is during such intervention

As i have panel data for each invidual it is the most powerfull to determine this effect at an invidual level. However, i am not sure how to determine if i should use a fixed, a random or mixed model.

Can someone give me suggestions/advice how to approach this?